# Using of gnome terminal to get new tab

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome

I'm new to scripting.

I’m using the below code in my project, but the terminal is getting closed instantly. I want the hold the terminal and keep running

```
#!/bin/bash/

gnome-terminal --tab --working-directory="/home/sandhya/OpenBTS/public/openbts/trunk/apps/" -e "file = grep OpenBTS /home/sandhya/OpenBTS/public/openbts/trunk/apps \
if [ -f $file ] \
then \
         echo " file exits" \
     sudo "/home/sandhya/OpenBTS/public/openbts/trunk/apps/OpenBTS" \

fi"
```

I want the terminal to be stay and keep running the application.

Please correct me in case the method or syntax I used is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In `gnome-terminal`,

--`go to Edit -> Profiles.`

--Double click on `Default` profile

--Click on `Title And Command` tab.

--Select `Hold Terminal Opens` from `when command exits` list which located at bottom of window.

--close windows

Now run your script it will work

Or you can also add your profile and run script as follows

Click the `New` tab. and give your profile name

Select Hold the terminal from the drop-down menu labelled When command exits. You should create a new profile for that and execute with

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=NAMEOFTHEPROFILE -e command
```

To make the terminal stay when the command exits:

In `konsole` there is a `--noclose` flag.

In `xterm`, there is a `-hold` flag.